# How can JWT be compromised in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, jwt

I've googled and readed a lot of articles for jwt security. A lot of people said that it is not safe to save the token in the local storage. But nobody actually gives some example of that IN ACTION.
For example how can somoene make XXS attacks with jwt in the local storage ?

The only example that i found is this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g21uHNIIewM

But here he at 3:10, he is explaning not about xss attack,but possible scenario if somoene acccess to my pc if i leave it unintentionally open, he can copy my jwt from localstorage, save it and then when he paste to his pc at home he has acceess to everything for example admin-routes.

But i didn't found an example for that, how can somoene directly make something bad with the jwt token.
For example i have web app, the users needs to register and after that login. I have this payload in my JWT, where i will give admin roles only to specific users ( with migration only at the beggining i give admin true to some users,after that for every other new registerd user he gets admin - false )

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin":false,
  "id":1
}
```

When user logs in i save the jwt sended from the server in the local storage for example.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJhZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsImlkIjoxfQ.GY9qxlilipXdndTGHWGcI-BDIkZFV5xjxOW-EVTHCQs
```

I have admin panels where
i am hiding the routes for them, and preventing access if the user role is not admin - so first i read the payload from the stored jwt

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
let jwtObject = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
// and i get
{name: "John Doe", admin: false, id: 1}
```

i check in the route

```
if(jwtObject.admin == true) {...};
```

Let's say some user wants to do something bad with my web app.He sign up, he logs in, he get jwt payload
where admin is false. He can also view his token for example

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJhZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsImlkIjoxfQ.GY9qxlilipXdndTGHWGcI-BDIkZFV5xjxOW-EVTHCQs
```

in the local storage. How can he do 'something' so he can change the payload it self - make admin to be true, even it is sended from server as false, and after that he would have access to all routes for the admin panels ?

I tagged here angular and react as well, so i will hear opinions and examples from more people regarding on the java script tools they are using.

Comment: It is better to keep user roles such as admin, customer etc. in the database rather than relying on the token itself. If you can only store user id in the token, you can then query user's name, role, email etc. by querying your database.

Comment: Your Jwt has no business saying that a user is an admin or not, because it can be changed wherever you store it. Instead, send the token to your backend and have the response decide if it's an admin role or not

Comment: As long as you don't trust your front-end, and always check the signature in the backend, you shouldn't worry. Storing the `admin` boolean in the frontend is fine and quite useful when you have a single page app, to show the user only what he needs to see. If a non-admin changes the token to make `admin: true`  and can access an admin vue, who cares? Because you will always check the signature before returning the data to populate that vue. Keycloak, the most popular IAM, does exactly that. It stores the role in the token, for use in the front-end

Comment: Tnx for your responses. But blex  i don't understand.What you mean by - always check the signature - ? When he change the payload admin - true then when i check if admin is true this statement will be true and he will access to the admin route

Comment: It becomes clear once you know what a JWT token is and how it works. It contains some data, which, you are right, can be modified. But the last part of the token is a signature, which is a hash of that data, encrypted with a private key of yours, which only your server has. Your front-end can trust the data without checking the signature, because it won't have a lot of impact. But your backend should always check that the signature matches with the data. If someone puts `true`, the signature won't match, you'll know the token has not been issued by your server, you'll block the request

Comment: if you change the payload of the token the token gets invalid. here an video.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arkGcbMkWJM

Comment: Yes i understand i saved the secret key as env variable in nodejs.So when the user comes to some route, i will send http request which will check the token at the backend, and then will give true or false - to give access or not to some route ?

Comment: i personally only store the ID of the user and nothing else. i also store it inside an cookie with httpOnly flag to `true` so only servers can read the cookie

Comment: i have an SPA where i check if user is logged in or not with the token. If he is i grant him access to the app otherwise i redirect. Technically he could still reach the route because an SPA is usually build with react or vue with is javascript that runs inside the browser. However, if he reach the route without token he will not be able to see the data because the data is only viewable with an valid token. but he hasnt one. that means he might see an empty UI or an UI witch has only loading indicators that will never load

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you have have an HTTPS and you don't put passwords in your JWT it's fine.
The user token information it's something that the user itself knows about like email, role, etc.. maybe you can encode it in base64 so it's a bit confusing for normal users.

Also, an important thing is to have a strong security validator for that token, so the user can't change it's signature and maybe it's role, there are a couple token helper libraries out there and some backend handling to check if the token is the same as it was sent in the past. And last thing, refresh tokens.